# Consulta de Eloquent a dos tablas a la vez

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy empezando con Eloquent y me he quedado atascado en una consulta que no logro entender como realizarla.
Quiero sacar todos datos de las ligas de la tabla ligas, de las ligas que tengan partidos en la tabla partidos.

La tabla ligas es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la tabla partidos es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo es esto, pero claramente no está bien porque funciona si solo me devuelve una liga.
Si me devuelve más ligas, no funcionaria. Como se hace para anidar una dentro de otra?

```
    $id_de_ligas = Partido::distinct()->get(['liga_id']);
    $info_ligas = Liga::where('id', $asd[0]->liga_id)->get();
```

Comment: Buenas! Si tengo las relaciones en los modelos. He visto que puedo sino añadir la consulta de mysql a lo bestia. 
DB::select('SELECT * FROM `ligas` WHERE id in (select DISTINCT(`liga_id`) from partidos)');
Pero es que me gustaría aprender el potencial de Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es extraer los id unicos de la tabla partidos asi

```
$ids = Partido::select('liga_id')->distinct()->get()->pluck('liga_id')->toArray();
```

y lo conviertes en un array para poderlo pasar como parámetro en la clausula where in que buscaras en tu otro modelo de la siguiente forma

```
 $info_ligas = Liga::whereIn('id',$ids )->get();
```

esto te debe traer todas las ligas que esten unicamente presentes en los partidos